# How to view the source code of a link that keeps redirecting?

Tags: html

I am attempting to view the HTML source code of the following link like so in chrome:

```
view-source:https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math/mental-math-test-easy/submit
```

But it just redirects to

```
view-source:https://rankyourbrain.com/mental-math/mental-math-test-easy
```

What is happening? Is there a way to prevent this (or view source another way)?

Also, let me know if this is the incorrect forum to ask this question...

Comment: In Chrome's Developer Tool > Network Tab, you can tick "Preserve log" to retain the records of the page before the redirection. However, you cannot stop the redirection.

Comment: I guess its because they haven't applied any webpage or code t the /submit route. Maybe, its just a post router which takes in some data

Comment: Thanks to both! I think it is a PHP page indeed, so I can't really see anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the website you wish to view-source, hit `F12` inside Chrome to view the debugger. On the Network tab, click the `Preserve log` checkbox.

Now you can view source without the redirects preventing the source-view page from displaying.

---

Alternatively, you could use a browser like Safari (on MacOS) to view source and the redirects won't affect it.